# Notepad++ add space between two lines

Tags: notepad++

I want to add four blank caracteres between two recurring lines.
I abused the trim traling space function, but only one line didn't need that and now i have too many files to fix it manually.

```
1    $構文名 = $SYSTEM_present_process;
2
3    SetTextWindow();
```

to

(the second line is supposed to have four blank spaces)

```
1    $構文名 = $SYSTEM_present_process;
2    
3    SetTextWindow();
```

[To let things more easier to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlZyI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `SYSTEM_present_process;\R\K(?=\R\h+SetTextWindow)`
- Replace with:      # 4 spaces
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
SYSTEM_present_process;     # literally
\R                          # any kind of linebreak
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this position
(?=                         # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    \R                          # any kind of linebreak
    \h+                         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    SetTextWindow               # literally
)                           # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]